# MySql Dynamic Period Columns from Rows Conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, row

I am having issue about converting rows data to columns. Let's say I have this kind of data on table **the_table**

```
YEAR | MONTH | ASPECT | VALUE | 
-------------------------------
2015 |   1   | Target |  90   |
2015 |   1   | Score  |  75   |
2015 |   2   | Target |  78   |
2015 |   2   | Score  |  80   |
2015 |   3   | Target |  90   |
2015 |   3   | Score  |  100  |
2015 |   4   | Target |  60   |
2015 |   4   | Score  |  90   |
```

Then I would like to change it into something like this. The number of columns is dynamically chosen by user (by range). For example, if user chooses range between period 1 and 3, the result will be

```
ASPECT | PERIOD1 | PERIOD2 |
----------------------------
Target |   90    |   78    | 
Score  |   75    |   80    |
```

for now, I am using query such as

```
select PERIOD1.ASPECT, PERIOD1.VALUE, PERIOD2.VALUE
from
(
select ASPECT, VALUE
from the_table
where year = 2015
and period = 1
) PERIOD1,
(
select ASPECT, VALUE
from the_table
where year = 2015
and period = 2
) PERIOD2
where PERIOD1.ASPECT = PERIOD2.ASPECT
```

Do you have any idea how to deal with this thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Number of columns chosen? Period or month?

Comment: Basically user can only choose month (year is alway same)

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively trying to create a pivot table. You can accomplish this by chaining together quite a few joins, here's one that works for your sample data:

```
select q1.aspect, q1.value 'period 1', q2.value 'period 2', q3.value 'period 3'
  from 
    (select aspect, value 
       from the_table 
         where month = 1
    ) q1
    inner join
    (select aspect, value
       from the_table
         where month = 2
    ) q2
    on q1.aspect = q2.aspect
    inner join
    (select aspect, value
       from the_table
         where month = 3
    ) q3
    on q1.aspect = q3.aspect;
```

The general form there is tedious, but simple to expand.

Here's a demo fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eb5d/9

And here's a slightly more specific version that uses a little bit of voodoo math to work:

```
select aspect, 
  sum(value * (1 - abs(sign(month - 1)))) as 'period 1', 
  sum(value * (1 - abs(sign(month - 2)))) as 'period 2', 
  sum(value * (1 - abs(sign(month - 3)))) as 'period 3'
from the_table
group by aspect
```

Which can be seen compared to the first query here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eb5d/13